# add some more in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, roman

i want to add the contents eg Abstract in table of  contents  which should have a  roman letter to it..  i have shown  below[image]

Comment: Welcome to SE. Your question is quit common here. Do you "google" in SE and general for similar problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the effect of `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` in this MWE. With these commands, the abstract could be a normal chapter of the front matter part.

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\chapter{Abstract}
\chapter{Acknowledgements}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listoftables \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Background}
\begin{figure} ... \caption{A figure} \end{figure}
\begin{table} ... \caption{A table}  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That adds the number of the last page of the list to the toc, which isn't a problem if the list is only one page long.

Comment: @Johannes_B Your are right, but I hoped that one can guess that the number also  can be added starting a  page, before of the list command.

Answer (score 1):

The usage of `tocbibind` prevents explicit `\addcontentsline` for the LoF and `LoT`

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\chapter{Abstract}
\chapter{Acknowledgements}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures 
\listoftables
\mainmatter


\chapter{First chapter}
\section{Some about the theory on Brontosaurs}


\begin{figure}
  \caption{A dummy figure} 
\end{figure}



\begin{table} 
\caption{A dummy table}  
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I may have misread the question- are you wanting to list the contents as an entry in the table of contents? If so, you could try this:

```
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}
```

This will create an entry for the contents page in your table of contents. The position of the command `\addcontentsline` (i.e. before or after `\tableofcontents`) will determine the page number that LaTeX assigns the entry.

Provided you include this command after `\pagenumbering{roman}` and before `\pagenumbering{arabic}`, the page number will be Roman numerals as you desire (unless you are using the `book` document class, which I believe does this automatically if you declare `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter` etc).

It would help if you showed us a minimal working example (i.e. your LaTeX file) so we can see how you are constructing your table of contents. People will then be able to give you a much more specific answer.